# Ansible with_items if item is defined

Tags: ansible

Ansible 1.9.4.

The script should execute some task only on hosts where some variable is defined. It works fine normally, but it doesn't work with the `with_items` statement.

```
- debug: var=symlinks
  when: symlinks is defined

- name: Create other symlinks
  file: src={{ item.src }} dest={{ item.dest }} state=link
  with_items: "{{ symlinks }}"
  when: symlinks is defined
```

But I get:

```
TASK: [app/symlinks | debug var=symlinks] *********************
skipping: [another-host-yet]

TASK: [app/symlinks | Create other symlinks] ******************
fatal: [another-host-yet] => with_items expects a list or a set
```

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

Comment: What is the value of `symlinks`?

Comment: The problem is that the same host, this variable is not defined

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
with_items: "{{ symlinks | default([]) }}"
```

Answer (score 31):

The reason for this behavior is conditions work differently inside loops. If a loop was defined the condition is evaluated for every item while iterating over the items. But the loop itself requires a valid list.

This is also mentioned [in the docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#using-conditionals-in-loops):

> Note that when combining when with with_items (see [Loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops)), be aware that the when statement is processed separately for each item. This is by design:

```
tasks:
  - command: echo {{ item }}
    with_items: [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ]
    when: item > 5
```

<sub>I think this is a bad design choice and for this functionality they better should have introduced something like `with_when`.</sub>

As you have already figured out yourself, you can default to an empty list.

```
with_items: "{{ symlinks  | default([]) }}"
```

Finally if the list is dynamically loaded from a var, say `x`, use:

```
with_items: "{{ symlinks[x|default('')] | default([])}}"
```

This will default to an empty list when 'x' is undefined

Accordingly, fall back to an empty dict with `default({})`:

```
# service_facts skips, then dict2items fails?
with_dict: "{{ ansible_facts.services|default({})|dict2items|selectattr('key', 'match', '[^@]+@.+\\.service')|list|items2dict }}"
```