# ansible execute task if key exist in a dictionary variable

Tags: loops, ansible, conditional-statements

I have a playbook having as input a dictionary.
I want to execute a task on 4 'items' only if they exist in dictionary.

I did a simple playbook for testing

```
---
- hosts: 127.0.0.1
  gather_facts: False

  vars:
    my_dict:
      level1:
        level10: niveau_10
      level2: niveau_2

  tasks:
    - name: display dictionary content
      debug: var=my_dict

    - name: iterate over dict
      debug: var="{{item}}"
      with_items:
        - my_dict.level2
        - my_dict.level1.level10
        - my_dict.level3
      when: item is defined
```

When I execute my playbook, I was expecting not to see any output for my_dict.level3 but it appears, how can I execute my test correctly?

```
bash$ ansible-playbook -i hosts test_item.yml

PLAY [127.0.0.1] **************************************************************************************************

TASK [display dictionary content] *********************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "my_dict": {
        "level1": {
            "level10": "niveau_10"
        },
        "level2": "niveau_2"
    }
}

TASK [iterate over dict] ******************************************************************************************
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=my_dict.level2) => {
    "item": "my_dict.level2",
    "my_dict.level2": "niveau_2"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=my_dict.level1.level10) => {
    "item": "my_dict.level1.level10",
    "my_dict.level1.level10": "niveau_10"
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=my_dict.level3) => {
    "item": "my_dict.level3",
    "my_dict.level3": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Thanks for your feedbacks.

S,

Comment: please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35471907/5736671): "The reason for this behavior is conditions work differently inside loops. If a loop was defined the condition is evaluated for every item while iterating over the items."

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"When I execute my playbook, I was expecting not to see any output for my_dict.level3 but it appears, how can I execute my test correctly?"*

A: In a loop an `item` is always defined and `"when: item is defined"` is always `true`.

It's possible to simply test the "bare variable". See [CONDITIONAL_BARE_VARS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#conditional-bare-vars) and try

```
  when: item
  ignore_errors: true
```

The abridged output should look like (excluding warnings and error)

```
"ansible_loop_var": "item", 
"item": "my_dict.level2", 
"my_dict.level2": "niveau_2"

"ansible_loop_var": "item", 
"item": "my_dict.level1.level10", 
"my_dict.level1.level10": "niveau_10"

...ignoring

localhost: ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=1
```

---

Notes

- It seems like inconsistency with the claim that `when` by default expands variables.
- See [Undefined built-in variable when used within a loop #49294](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/49294) how the variables are evaluated inside a loop. There seem to be unresolved challenges.